# Getting variable encryption results with VB.Net and DES

Tags: vb.net, encryption, des

I'm working on an semi-internal encryption process for somewhat sensitive information. Email addresses and the like. I'm working with a few other developers at some sister companies on the project, and the requirements are that everyone's encryption can talk to everyone else's. We use a global password, encrypt and decrypt information onsite, and that's about it.

My problem is that my encryption procedure, while matching theirs, is giving me variable results. I'm currently polling our SQL server for the strings to be encrypted in question, iterating through the array of results, and updating the server with the encrypted strings.

The problem is that the first string is always different from all subsequent strings, and isn't recognized as valid by the testing software we're supposed to be basing our solution off of. The second and all subsequent strings come through just fine.

Example:

```
test@test.com - BrPURPlWW7+VYrR5puJ/JHXoIp/MV5WR
test@test.com - BrPURPlWW79h+n4Tgot0xRmM7SdWQQsy
test@test.com - BrPURPlWW79h+n4Tgot0xRmM7SdWQQsy
```

I can't quite figure out what's going on, because I can encrypt and decrypt back and forth on my own machine with no issues. Any advice would be lovely.

My encryption function follows:

```
Private TripleDES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider     
Sub New(ByVal key As String)        
    Dim ivHash(), keyHash() As Byte

    keyHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
    ReDim Preserve keyHash(7)
    TripleDES.Key = keyHash

    ivHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Empty)
    ReDim Preserve ivHash(7)
    TripleDES.IV = ivHash
End Sub

Public Function EncryptData(ByVal Plaintext As String) As String
    Dim PlaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Plaintext)
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDES.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    TripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

    encStream.Write(PlaintextBytes, 0, PlaintextBytes.Length)
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
End Function

Public Function DecryptData(ByVal EncryptedText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedText)
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDES.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    TripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

    decStream.Write(EncryptedBytes, 0, EncryptedBytes.Length)
    decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `TripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB` after you have called `TripleDES.CreateEncryptor()`, so the first encryption is using the default value of `CipherMode.CBC`.  Since `TripleDES` is reused, after the first call to `EncryptData` its `Mode` is set correctly.

Move `TripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB` into `New` and it should work consistently.

Comment: I knew it was gonna be something simple and dumb. Thanks!